# How to store Images in S3 bucket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3

in my express application, I have my images being saved to a folder in my repo.

However i dont think this is correct i should store them somewhere else, i thought s3 would be a good option.

Ive never done it before so i have no idea how it works.

My  currrent code saves the image after scaling it:

```
exports.resize = async (req, res, next) => {
  // check if there is no new file to resize
  if (!req.file) {
    next(); // skip to the next middleware
    return;
  }
  const extension = req.file.mimetype.split('/')[1]
  req.body.photo = `${uuid.v4()}.${extension}`
  // now we resize
  const photo = await jimp.read(req.file.buffer)


  await photo.cover(300, 300);
  // await photo.resize(800, jimp.AUTO);

  await photo.write(`./public/uploads/${req.body.photo}`);
  // once we have written the photo to our filesystem, keep going!
  next()
};
```

Whats the process in order to save the images to aws s3?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Create file upload service

```
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

aws.config.update({
    // Your SECRET ACCESS KEY from AWS should go here,
    // Never share it!
    // Setup Env Variable, e.g: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    secretAccessKey: "ab7786ad6",
    // Not working key, Your ACCESS KEY ID from AWS should go here,
    // Never share it!
    // Setup Env Variable, e.g: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID
    accessKeyId: "ab7786ad6",
    region: 'us-east-1' // region of your bucket
});

const s3 = new aws.S3();
```

> create an instance of our Amazon S3.

```
const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'medium-test',
    acl: 'public-read',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString())
    }
  })
})

module.exports = upload;
```

> Setup a route to upload image

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const upload = require('../services/multer');

const singleUpload = upload.single('image')

router.post('/image-upload', function(req, res) {
  singleUpload(req, res, function(err, some) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(422).send({errors: [{title: 'Image Upload Error', detail: err.message}] });
    }

    return res.json({'imageUrl': req.file.location});
  });
})

module.exports = router;
```

for more reference : https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-set-up-simple-image-upload-with-node-and-aws-s3-84e609248792

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [AWS SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) on npm.

From here you will need to configure the package to connect to your buckets..

some useage would be :

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
});
```

\
You could convert the image to base64 in nodeJS for sending later.

And a regular upload method written :

```
const uploadFile = () => {
  fs.readFile(fileName, (err, data) => {
     if (err) throw err;
     const params = {
         Bucket: 'testBucket', //  bucket name
         Key: 'image.png', // filename
         Body: JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
     };
     s3.upload(params, function(s3Err, data) {
         if (s3Err) throw s3Err;
         console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`);
     });
  });
};
```

Ref  : [AWS Api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/welcome.html)